# Using ActiveRecord, is there a way to get the old values of a record during after_update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model, callback

**Setup using a simple example:** I've got 1 table (`Totals`) that holds the sum of the `amount` column of each record in a second table (`Things`).

When a `thing.amount` gets updated, I'd like to simply add the difference between the old value and the new value to `total.sum`.

Right now I'm subtracting `self.amount` during `before_update` and adding `self.amount` during `after_update`.  This places WAY too much trust in the update succeeding.

**Constraint:**  I don't want to simply recalculate the sum of all the transactions.

**Question:** Quite simply, I'd like to access the original value during an `after_update` callback.  What ways have you come up with do this?

**Update:** I'm going with Luke Francl's idea.  During an `after_update` callback you still have access to the `self.attr_was` values which is exactly what I wanted.  I also decided to go with an `after_update` implementation because I want to keep this kind of logic in the model.  This way, no matter how I decide to update transactions in the future, I'll know that I'm updating the sum of the transactions correctly. Thanks to everyone for your implementation suggestions.

Answer (score 163, accepted):

Ditto what everyone is saying about transactions.

That said...

ActiveRecord as of Rails 2.1 keeps track of the attribute values of an object. So if you have an attribute `total`, you will have a `total_changed?` method and a `total_was` method that returns the old value.

There's no need to add anything to your model to keep track of this anymore.

**Update:** Here is the documentation for [ActiveModel::Dirty](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html) as requested.

Comment: I thought something like this existed.  Can you link to the relevant documentation about attr_changed? and attr_was?

Comment: Sure, I added a link to the answer.

Answer (score 14):

To get all changed fields, with their old and new values respectively:

```
person = Person.create!(:name => 'Bill')
person.name = 'Bob'
person.save
person.previous_changes        # => {"name" => ["Bill", "Bob"]}
```

Comment: I believe the last line should now read `person.previous_changes` instead of `person.changes`

Answer (score 12):

Appending "_was" to your attribute will give you the previous value before saving the data.

These methods are called [dirty methods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html) methods.

Cheers!

Answer (score 9):

Some other folks are mentioning wrapping all this in a transaction, but I think that's done for you; **you just need to trigger the rollback by raising an exception for errors in the after_* callbacks.**

See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

> The entire callback chain of a save, save!, or destroy call runs within a transaction. That includes after_* hooks. If everything goes fine a COMMIT is executed once the chain has been completed.
>
> If a before_* callback cancels the action a ROLLBACK is issued. You can also trigger a ROLLBACK raising an exception in any of the callbacks, including after_* hooks. Note, however, that in that case the client needs to be aware of it because an ordinary save will raise such exception instead of quietly returning false.

Answer (score 7):

[ActiveRecord::Dirty](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Dirty) is a module that's built into ActiveRecord for tracking attribute changes. So you can use `thing.amount_was` to get the old value.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to get value of particular field after update you can use field_before_last_save method.

```
Example:

u = User.last
u.update(name: "abc")

u.name_before_last_save will give you old value (before update value)
```

Answer (score 4):

From **Rails 5.1**, the behavior of `attribute_was` inside of after callbacks have change. `attribute_was` will return the value after the save is done and return the current value in an `after_save` or `after_update` callback.

[`attribute_before_last_save` is invoked two ways](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Dirty.html#method-i-attribute_before_last_save) to get the previous value of a field in the `after_save` and `after_update` callbacks right now:

Option #1

```
attribute_before_last_save('yourfield')
```

Option #2

```
*_before_last_save
```

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your model:

```
def amount=(new_value)
    @old_amount = read_attribute(:amount)
    write_attribute(:amount,new_value)
end
```

Then use @old_amount in your after_update code.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should be doing this in a transaction to ensure that your data gets written together.

To answer your question, you could just set a member variable to the old value in the before_update, which you can then access in the after_update, however this isn't a very elegant solution.

Comment: I'm struggling to see how i would implement what i want using a transaction.  Does a transaction like this live in the model or in the controller?  Do I remove my 'after_update' and 'before_update' callbacks? Finally, how do I get the old value that i need in order to determine the difference?

Comment: nevermind, i see that i have to place the code in the controller.  we're good.

Answer (score 0):

Idea 1: Wrap the update in a database transaction, so that if the update fails your Totals table isn't changed: [ActiveRecord Transactions docs](http://www.railsbrain.com/api/rails-2.2.2/doc/index.html?a=C00000598&name=ActiveRecord::Transactions::ClassMethods)

Idea 2: Stash the old value in @old_total during the before_update.